# How do you display the stream name? [ICECAST]

Tags: php, stream, icecast

I took a part of PHP code from a different Stackoverflow question, and it works perfectly.

```
<?php header>

//Display IceCast Server Stats

$server = "***********"; //IP (x.x.x.x or domain name)
$iceport = "8070"; //Port
$iceurl = "live"; //Mountpoint
$online = "<font color=green><b>ONLINE</b> </font><br />";
$offline = "<font color=red><b>OFFLINE</b></font><br />";

if($fp = @fsockopen($server, $iceport, $errno, $errstr, '1')) {
        fclose($fp);
        $ice_status=$online;
        echo "<p><b>DJ:</b> $ice_status";
        $stats = file("http://" . $server . ":" . $iceport . "/status2.xsl");
        $status = explode(",", $stats[5]);
        $artist = explode("-", $status[5]);
echo " " . $artist[1];
echo " - ";
        echo " " . $artist[2];
echo "<br />";
//      echo "<b>Listeners:</b> <b> " . $status[3] . "</b>";
        echo "</p>";
//echo "<br />";
//echo "<p><a href=http://" . $server . ":" . $iceport . "/" . $iceurl . " target=new><b>Listen!</b></a></p>";

 } else {

        $ice_status=$offline;
        echo "<p><b>DJ:</b> $ice_status";
}

?>
<hr />
</center>
```

I'm trying to add the stream name, which is currently:
   echo "

**DJ:** $ice_status";
This displays DJ: ONLINE, but I want it to say DJ: (DJ Name/Stream Name)

I do believe its variables from status2.xsl, but I'm a complete noob at this, and can't seem to figure out how to use it. Could anyone tell me what streamname variable would be?

I was also wondering, is it possible to make it so the "nowplaying.php" refreshes, but my whole web page doesn't? I've tried an iframe, but it makes it look really bad, and has errors.

What my website looks like at the moment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/luc4O.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a look at TheFineManual™:

http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/server-stats.html#xslt

Especially the part about `status-json.xsl`. Make sure you are running an up to date version of Icecast. Icecast is available from all major Linux distributions in up to date packaging. Xiph provides [independent packaging](https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Installing_latest_version_(official_Xiph_repositories)), which is useful if there are no up to date packages for a distribution, e.g. shortly after an Icecast release.

`status2.xsl` was an example file, and a bad one at that. It was removed from newer Icecast versions.

Comment: Thanks.
I tried replacing 
"$ice_status" with
echo "<p><b>DJ:</b> $server_name";

But It doesn't work. I believe its the latest version, I'm running off Epichost, and it just says Icecast v2, no specifics.

https://i.gyazo.com/a389f8c20caee4d4ed6b15f8def5ffec.png